# Процесс в реальном времени

Tags: vb6, visual-basic, процесс

Часто приходится после запуска компилированной программы открывать Диспетчер задач и переключать процесс программы в режим реального времени. Знакомый сказал, что есть возможность переключать из программы VB6, но не помнит как) Может кто знает?

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю про Visual Basic, но в Win API для этого служит SetPriorityClass. Вот [тут](http://www.novicksoftware.com/TipsAndTricks/Tips-Lower-your-Process-Priority-with-the-Win32-API.htm) есть импорты для неё:

```
Private Declare Function SetPriorityClass Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal dwPriorityClass As Long) As Long

' Used by SetPriorityClass
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20
Private Const BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 16384
Private Const ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 32768
Private Const IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H40
Private Const HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H80
Private Const REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H100
```

А также вот такой пример (если SetPriorityClass не заработает) `ProcessPrioritySet(Priority:=ppBelowNormal)`